# mysql different server, same content, different count

Tags: mysql

I have 2 servers, live and beta, and have 2 identical databases between live and beta, but the count() return different number

LIVE:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_application_user` WHERE created >= '2014-06-01 00:00:01' and created < '2014-07-01 23:59:59';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     3432 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

BETA (ubuntu, mysql):

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_application_user` WHERE created >= '2014-06-01 00:00:01' and created < '2014-07-01 23:59:59';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     3444 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And when I try local mysql on my laptop (Windows 8.1, mysql), it returns the same number as the live.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_application_user` WHERE created >= '2014-06-01
00:00:01' and created < '2014-07-01 23:59:59';
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     3432 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
mysql>
```

What causes the BETA server to return different number?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you _sure_ the two databases are absolutely identical?

Comment: You are sure you have in all databases the same data?

Comment: pretty sure, the total all records (select count(*) from tbl_appication_user) are identical, just the select count using date range is different.

Comment: If you try to select all data with `< '2014-06-01
    00:00:01' and created >= '2014-07-01 23:59:59'` are you get the same difference? So i gess that the count of all recoreds are the same. but the creation date for 2 records was changed.

Comment: When you say "total is identical", how are you working the total?

Comment: just "select count(*) from tbl_appication_user"

Comment: Are all servers using the same timezone?

Comment: @mrjink ah! That's the correct answer! i changed the timezome on the beta server and the count returns correct number now. Thanks!
How to make a comment to be "accepted answer" ?

Comment: @user3620841 You can't accept comments. I've made it an answer, so you can accept that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone on the BETA server is probably different from the other machines.  Although times and dates are *stored* as UTC, they will be interpreted in the connection's time zone when used literally, as in the `WHERE` part of your query.

For your reference: [11.3.1 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default,
>   the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The
>   time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time
>   zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.
>   If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and
>   retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value
>   you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for
>   conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as
>   the value of the time_zone system variable. For more information, see
>   Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the created field is deferent in your twoo databases.

if you are using triggers for created field and replication this issue is normally casue of the time delay in replication

Comment: i used mysqldump to export from the live and import to beta using mysql -uroot -p db < dump.sql
was that also applied to your case?

Comment: you can select top n rows for example select top 10 or 100 rows to compare date created between twoo database tables . I think this difference cause of created field data is not same in twoo databases